# Shell$ExitCodeException running Spark locally on Windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark, local

I have worked with Spark for many months, and this morning, running my jobs crashes with the exceptions below.

The weird thing is that it has perfectly worked for many months, and i can't fiure out what has changed. This job succeed in cluster mode.

My setup :
- Run locally (for test)
- Windows 10
- Spark 1.6.2
- Java 1.8

```
2016-10-28 13:27:39 ERROR Executor:95 - Exception in task 6.0 in stage 41.0 (TID 210)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:848)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD$.writePartitionToCheckpointFile(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD$$anonfun$writeRDDToCheckpointDirectory$1.apply(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD$$anonfun$writeRDDToCheckpointDirectory$1.apply(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The jobs crashes at:

```
ALSModel model = als.fit(ratings.unionAll(virtualRatings));
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

I 777-chmoded the entire local drive, and that fixed the problem. I do not know what file/folder caused the issue

Comment: what about permissions? did u try to run application as an administrator?

Comment: @VladoDemcak Not sure if this is what you mean, but I ran Eclipse in administrator mode and te issue still persists. I also gave full access to my folders. My user in admin on this machine. I have rewritten the script with Spark 2.0.1 in scala, and the problem is still there...

Comment: Problem solved (original post edited)